# Java Codelab Letter Counter

Tags: java

```
File Letter Counter
```

Write a program  that asks the user to enter the name  of a file, and then asks the user to
enter a character . The program  should count and display the number of times that the
specified character  appears in the file. Use Notepad or another text editor to create a
sample file that can be used to test the program .

Could someone explain why the count is not working, I always get an output of 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class TESTTEST
{
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter file name:"); 

    String linestr = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase(); 
    System.out.print(" Enter character to count:"); 

    char ch = sc.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0); 

    int count = 0; 
    for(char ch0:linestr.toCharArray()) { 
    if(ch0 == ch) 
    count++; 
    } 
    System.out.println(" The character " + "'"+ch+"'" + " appears in the file wc4 " + count +  " times."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see what it's doing?

Comment: Yes, I used the code and it just outputs 0 for the amount the character appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are currently checking for the character in the *name* of the file, not the file itself. You should actually take in the full file path, unless the file is in the same directory, in which case you can take just the name (as this is the local path).

Here's your code modified to allow reading from a file:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class TESTTEST
{
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter file path:"); 

    //This is the path to the file you want to read from
    String path = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print(" Enter character to count:"); 

    char ch = sc.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    //read all lines into a list
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int count = 0; 
    for(String linestr:lines){
        for(char ch0:linestr.toCharArray()) { 
            if(ch0 == ch) 
                count++; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" The character " + "'"+ch+"'" + " appears in the file wc4 " + count +  " times."); 
    }
}
```

Also please look at the [documentation for `Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and note that this function is not intended for reading in large files. Use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead on large files.